Is Open JDK 8 supported in weblogic 12.2.1.4?
Right now we are using oracle JDK 8 with weblogic 12.2.1.4 version.
Our team is planning to move from ORACLE JDK to Open JDK.
So just want to confirm will Open JDK 8 is supported in 12.2.1.4 without any problems?
What will be the impact of moving to Open JDK?

it's not certified, I can't access this one, it should fail to install if it doesn't like your jdk

WebLogic Server MUST run under Oracle JDK. OpenJDK will fail to run it.
If you are afraid of your Java License (Oracle) it is included with your WebLogic Server license.

It works, but its not recommended as you can see on documentation:
Java Development Kit (JDK) Requirements
To run the installers in the 12c (12.2.1.4.0), you must have a certified JDK already installed on your system. Most Fusion Middleware products are available as platform-generic distributions in .jar file format. Some products (for example, Oracle HTTP Server) have a .bin (for UNIX operating systems) or .exe (for Windows operating systems) installer. In the 12c (12.2.1.4.0), the Fusion Middleware products, the platform-specific distributions no longer include and configure a JDK automatically.
When the document was published, the certified JDK was jdk1.8.0_211 and it has to be 64 bit. For information about the latest certified JDKs, refer to the certification document for your software version listed in Oracle Fusion Middleware Supported System Configurations page.
**Note:It is a best practice to use a separate JDK location than the one installed on the system. One that you can manage and maintain with the Fusion Middleware products. See, Doc ID 1492980.1 How to Install and Maintain the Java SE Installed or Used with FMW 11g or 12c Products. This ensures that the Oracle Fusion Middleware software is using the proper version of the JDK software.
